# Wordpress Page Update and Plugin Install Reverting Back

Tags: wordpress

I'm a noob at Wordpress as so please don't flame me. My question is why is it that when I update a page or install plugin, it reverts back and its changes I made is not working? When I click the preview changes button there are two changes. The first one is I made and then the second is when it reverts back Is there a plugin that restricts any changes? I'm logged in as admin. The plugins installed are:

> Akismet, Contact Form 7, DesignThemes Core Features Plugin,
>   FileBrowser, Hello Dolly, LayerSlider WP, Lightbox Plus Colorbox, Like
>   This, Magic Liquidizer Responsive Table, Price Table, Responsive
>   Styled Google Maps, Revolution Slider, Simple Lightbox, WooCommerce,
>   YITH WooCommerce Wishlist and YITH WooCommerce Zoom Magnifier

What should I do? Kindly please help me.

Comment: You problem is some what unclear. What do you mean by 'it reverts back'? Can explain it with some example so as to understand what is actually happening?

Comment: Hello sir thank you for your response. My scenario is when I edit the page (page tab on wordpress), then I select the page I want to change for example the header name (add some HTML code), the changes I made after pressing the update button will not reflect.. It just goes back to the one that I haven't updated yet.

Comment: can you display screenshot of the page you are trying edit, highlighting the area where you are adding the html code?